# How to check if the memory assigned to two servers are shared memory or not in IBM AIX?

Tags: memory, central-processing-unit, ibm, aix

I'm having two DB servers and two Application servers running on **IBM AIX 5.3 OS**

I'm using `Oracle DB 10.2.0.4` with `RAC` environment and EBS Application is `R12.1.3`.

In my DB server I could find I have `32 GB` each in both my DB servers and `32 GB` each in Application servers.

How can I check if the memory in both the nodes of DB and Application server are shared memory or it has been added to only one server.

That is, if I have `32 GB` in node 1 of DB server and `32 GB` in node 2 of DB server **how can I check if the `32GB` memory is not shared between the two servers** ?

I'm using `TOPAS` command to check the memory.

Please provide me a command to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[lparstat -i](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/lparstat.htm?view=kc#lparstat__row-d3e62911) in the partition includes `Memory Mode`, whether `Dedicated`, `Shared`, or if Active Memory Expansion is enabled, `Expanded`. Although, man page and Red book suggest active memory sharing is available with AIX 6.1 and later.

While you are at, check which frames each partition is running on. If you have more than one physical host, might as well spread the application across them, in case one fails.

You should upgrade the OS, 5.3 is end of service.

I recommend `Dedicated` memory for nearly all workloads. Oversubscribing has some performance risk if the memory demands exceeds installed RAM.